# Why is the type integer?

Tags: r, dataframe, typeof

Why is the typeof() yielding an integer when this is clearly a string?

```
> Str_IN$V1[trapper]
    [1] IT1*0000010*660*LB*4.07*PE*BP*2018710000*MP*12345*VN*944940
    20 Levels: BEG*20140905*93608602*20140730*45056564 CTT*1 DTM*011*20140904 ... TDS*280120

    > typeof(Str_IN$V1[trapper])
    [1] "integer"
```

Comment: It is `factor` where storage mode is `integer`.  Try `as.integer(factor(c("A", "B", "C"))`  You might be looking for `class(Str_IN$V1[trapper])`

Comment: You can use `class` instead of `typeof` to get a little more information about the vector (though it does not always return a length-1 vector ... in many cases, it returns a vector of length 2 or more, as in `class(Sys.time())` and `class(as_tibble(mtcars))`).

Comment: Why is the storage mode an integer?Any reference to understand this better might be of help...@r2evans

Answer (score 2):

According to `?typeof`

> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

The OP's column is a `factor` and its internal storage mode is `integer`.  it can be checked with `mode`

```
mode(factor("A"))
#[1] "numeric"
```

and its `storage` version

```
storage.mode(factor("A"))
#[1] "integer"
```

Instead, we may have to check `class`

```
class(Str_IN$V1[trapper])
```